# Python PIL image from array datatype error

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've been playing around with PIL to get a hang of it and wanted to split up an image into its rgb channels, put it together again and show it.

```
import PIL.Image as Img
import numpy as np

img = Img.new('RGB', (10,10), color = 'cyan')
r,g,b = img.split()
pixels = np.array([np.asarray(r),np.asarray(g),np.asarray(b)])
new_img = Img.fromarray(pixels.astype(np.uint8))
new_img.show()
```

when I run the file it returns an Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2716, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey)
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 10), |u1
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
import PIL.Image as Img
import numpy as np

img = Img.new('RGB', (10,10), color = 'cyan')
r,g,b = img.split()
pixels = [np.asarray(r),np.asarray(g),np.asarray(b)]
new_img = Img.fromarray(pixels)
new_img.show()
```

Where I got this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2704, in fromarray
    arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

**So how do I have to put the r, g and b arrays back together correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB image is made by stacking 3 colored channels one over the other on the z-axis. See this image for analogy,

[image]

```
pixels = np.array([np.asarray(r),np.asarray(g),np.asarray(b)])
```

This command places those 3 colored channels side by side, you can check `shape` using

```
print(pixels.shape)

(3, 10, 10)
```

This makes no sense to the interpreter thus the error message.

Each pixel in an RBG image is a tuple of red, green and blue color values.

[image]

thus shape take the form `rows x cols x channels`. You can achieve this by using `np.stack`

```
pixels = np.stack([np.asarray(r),np.asarray(g),np.asarray(b)], axis = 2)
```